# Does language lessons paid by company count as work time?

Tags: work-time, training, czech-republic

I work in Europe and my company offers us a 2 hours long English lesson with native speaker once a week. They take place during normal working hours (afternoon), but they are voluntary. I'd gladly participate, but I don't have time to spend 2 extra hours on it, so I'd really want to know if such things count usually as work time.

Note: My work hours are flexible, so I know I don't have to be at work during specific hours, instead I need to work X hours during whole week.

Comment: When I lived in The Netherlands the Dutch class was considered working time but you have a very simple solution: **ask your employer**...

Comment: You need to specify your country, europe is not enough to infer about the work law applicable to you. Also it may depend of your type of contract (hourly or daily), if you clock in/out, ...

Comment: @JasonMarechal I work in Czech republic... and my salary is monthly, for 20 hours a week (part-timer)

Comment: Is English a requirement of the job? This may make a difference - if it's training that's required for you to be able to do your job, then it's more likely to be considered part of your working hours than if it's just a perk of the job.

Comment: @delinear it's IT, so yeah, we use English more than our native language here.. most of our communications. documentations etc are in English

Comment: You could try to just express your last sentence to your manager and see what she says: "[I'd like to participate in the English language training], but I don't have time to spend 2 extra hours on it (from my X required weekly hours)". She might say "oh, that's too bad." or she might say "you may log those hours as working time under project TPS."

Comment: This is company specific, only people working at your company can give you a definite answer. The best anyone else can do is speculate with a 50/50 chance of being right.

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is to talk to your manager. We can only speculate. It largely depends on the company. The company I work for allows us an hour a week for educational purposes (that are appropriate for the business). Other companies I have worked for was not so generous.

Comment: On the other hand, if the company pays for the instructor, and you refuse to donate your time, and if as a result your language abilities are not as good as required, then this is your own fault and will be held against you, with no excuses. It's of course good for the business if you improve your language skills, but it's also good for the business to hire someone else who has the skills in the first place. And consider that in the future this will add to your ability to get better paid jobs.